# Unresolved Imports - "help: a similar path exists"

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to Rust and am trying to set up a new project. I'd like to have code for a `parser`, `tokens`, and `addressing` for a little 6502 project in separate files. My `lib.rs` file is therefore set up as:

```
pub mod parse;
pub mod tokens;
pub mod addressing;
```

I'm running into two problems. First, if I try to use one of these modules, for example `parse`, from `main.rs` with `mod parse;` I get this error:

```
unresolved module, can't find module file: parse.rs, or parse/mod.rs
```

Despite the fact that `parse.rs` is literally in the same folder as the `main.rs` file. (I also tried the 2015 method of moving module code into named folders each containing a `mod.rs` file, with the same result). I should also note that the structs and functions I want to use from each of these files are declared `pub`.

Secondly, if I try to use any of the functions or structs from other files inside any of these files, like `use addressing;` I get the error:

```
 --> src\parse.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use addressing;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no external crate `addressing`
```

However, I am trying to use the `Address` struct here, and in the very same error message, the compiler suggests this!

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Address` in this scope
  --> src\parse.rs:10:14
   |
10 |     address: Address,
   |              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
2  | use crate::addressing::Address;
   |
```

So, I instead add `use crate::addressing::Address;` to the top of the file `parse.rs`, and a new error appears:

```
 --> src\parse.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use crate::addressing::Address;
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `corten::addressing`
```

`corten` *is* the name of my project, so fair enough, let's try `use corten::addressing;`:

```
 --> src\parse.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use corten::addressing::*;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `corten`
  |
```

...And, in fact, immediately underneath this error suggests the very same import syntax that it grumbled about earlier:

```
  --> src\parse.rs:10:14
   |
10 |     address: Address,
   |              ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
2  | use crate::addressing::Address;
   |
```

What is going on here? The compiler has lead me in complete circles, each time complaining about its own suggestions and fixes.

I have also checked other answers on here and seem to have set up my files as suggested in their fixes (although some are on a slightly outdated edition of Rust by now). I have also checked how other projects on GitHub handle this and I don't seem to be doing anything different. Can I just use my struct?

Comment: The first error is the problem, the second is just a cascaded error. But you mentioned both main.rs and lib.rs, which of them do you use?

Comment: "if I try to use one of these modules, for example parse, from main.rs with mod parse;" - you probably don't want to do this, if you already declared it as `pub mod parse` in `lib.rs`. Each file should have exactly one `mod` statement related to it. It's unclear how are you modules structured currently, so I can't make a definitive answer, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
 --> src\parse.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use crate::addressing::Address;
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `corten::addressing`
```

```
 --> src\parse.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use corten::addressing::*;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `corten`
  |
```

These two errors put together are enough to pin down the mistake you have made: you have both a `main.rs` and a `lib.rs`, which is fine, and you have put `mod parse;` in both of them, **which is not fine.**

The key thing to know here to understand the problem is that `main.rs` and `lib.rs` are the roots of *separate crates*. Thus, they are different compilation contexts, and code that works in one will not work in the other. Not only that, if it *did* work, you'd then have two separately-compiled copies of the same items — and as far as the Rust compiler is concerned, you'd have two distinct `Address` types.

In general, **only one `mod foo;` item should exist anywhere in your project for a given file `foo.rs`.**

Anything that is needed in multiple crates should be in your library crate, i.e. some module which is (or has a parent that is) declared in `lib.rs`. Then you `use corten::...` to refer to it from `main.rs` or any other binary (`tests/`, `examples/`…).

It's fine to write whatever `use` declarations are useful in any given file, because those just bring things into scope (they *shorten paths* that you could have written in fully-qualified form). But do not ever duplicate a `mod`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem now (and where I went wrong). I thought the `lib.rs` file was the file which 'uncovered' the modules I wanted to use in my project, so it needed to have both - having looked it up, I can see that I'm trying to compile this both as a binary and a library, which is the multiple contexts that you mentioned.